# Start youtube video with adb?

Tags: android, adb

How do I open youtube application and start playing some video?
For example this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRhFSWz_J3I

I tried to launch other applications successfully (for example playing local video on sdcard), but can't seem to find right way to start youtube (com.google.android.youtube).

Played local file

```
am start -n com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d "file:///sdcard/VideoTest/sample.mp4"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRhFSWz_J3I"
```

I'm not sure, if `-d` is necessary for the URI, try this if it does not work:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRhFSWz_J3I"
```

It may open the Chooser activity on first run though.

Comment: You should be able to identify the youtube component (perhaps by epxeriment with the chooser and looking in logcat) and then run that with an explicit intent

Comment: I used it before to start a web-site.. but I forgot that I could tell android before to open such links in YouTube app. This probably can work.

Comment: I am still curious how can I find the commands to start different applications (not just YouTube).

Comment: well, that depends on the manifest. but basically, most app have a MAIN intent-filter to get launched from the launcher. you could use that.

Comment: 22332112 - You can use **monkey runner** like this `adb shell monkey -p com.july.ndtv 1` where **1** is *number of instances* and `com.july.ndtv` is the **package name** where say if you want to launch Facebook, replace that with package name. Get it?

Answer (score 2):

you can find such a definition in the file AndroidManifest.xml of youtube play app:

```
<data android:scheme="vnd.youtube"/>
```

so, add "vnd.youtube:" to the head of youtube URL, for example:
"vnd.youtube:https://youtube.com/STH"

then run the adb command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "vnd.youtube:https://youtube.com/STH"
```

Comment: On my Android TV, such a command does nothing but flash the screen. Whereas this command does launch a video: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://youtube.com/watch?v=3pv01sSq44w" com.google.android.youtube.tv`